# Autofill forms - wrong username saved making users think the password is faulty

Tags: usability, login, autofill

Is there a way to notify the user that they have saved incorrect credentials? Currently users think their password is at fault and reset is, leading them to receive an email with the correct username and new password. However, autocomplete still fills in the wrong username leading to another failed login. It leads to a lot of frustration.. is there a way to combat this?

Edit: the website contains highly sensitive information so security is a concern.

Comment: You can set <form autofill="off"> it's not a great UX but backed up with Andrew's solution, it might work, in fact you could add this setting if they have a first failed log-in, so they're forced to type it.

Comment: Is this supported for all browsers?

Comment: At  the moment, yes, but I believe the new specification details deprecation of this setting.

Comment: @DarrylGodden I like the idea of removing autofill for retry attempts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Please carefully check you username and password before trying again"

You're not going to be able to change their autocomplete settings or counter against faulty autocomplete data.

The only other solution is to offer an extended session similar to services like Facebook (or even StackExchange) where users simply don't log out but a session cookie holds a key for recovering the username of the last user on that device and only asks for a password when the session finally expires - but that's a technical solution that would require significant investment from your development team.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'll consult IT and see if this is viable for us.